# How to implement a counter for a specific timeframe using Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a solution for a counter for specific documents in Firebase's Firestore database, but with the added requirement that I need it to keep count of the documents between specific timestamps.

So, for example, we have a bunch of documents in our "videos" collection which hold information related to each video. Each video document also has a subcollection "statistics" which holds a timestamped view for each time the given video is viewed. We do have an aggregate counter on the video document which is incremented each time a view is added to its statistics subcollection, but this only gives the number of *total views*. We need to be able to query the number of views in the last 7 days as well as the last 30 days.

As you can appreciate, querying all of the view documents in the subcollection using range filters is not a good solution server-side nor client-side because the number of view documents scales into the millions which would be costly.

Does anyone have a solution for a counter for views in the past x days? I just can't think of a way to ensure it's updated accurately without having to query the possibly millions of view documents.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a collection called statistics that has a document for each video. Each video has a map of data with timestamps and values. I would bucket every few hours into a single timestamp range.

Perhaps every 3 hours:

```
Statistics
--- Video1
------ Plays
--------- TimestampRangeStart
--------- Play Count

--------- TimestampRangeStart
--------- Play Count

--------- TimestampRangeStart
--------- Play Count
```

Then you can query for all videos where `TimestampRangeStart > 7 days ago` to retrieve a list of all videos that have been played in the last week. This would return the document and then clientside you can just sum up the play counts for all ranges within the last 7 days.

If you're worried about space in the Firestore documents you can consider only adding a map entry if there's a view, so if nobody watches a video then you don't need to worry about an entry. Alternatively you can make the ranges bigger.